# litecoin transaction time without transaction fee

Tags: litecoin

I've sent 927 ltc from my wallet to btc-e but didn't left enough in my wallet to cover the 0.01 transaction fee. My litecoin wallet is showing 'this payment has not been transmitted yet' and it's been a couple of days now. How long is it going to take? Is there a way to cancel the transaction?

Comment: did it confirm by now?

Comment: same problem here. not confirmed since 5 jan

Answer (score 1):

You may find the solutions offered here to be of help:

```
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23012/btc-stuck-with-zero-confirmations
```

see also:

```
https://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/wiki/UnstickLowFeeTransactions
```