# BTC stuck with zero confirmations

Tags: transactions, wallet

I sent BTC from my blockchain.info wallet to my other wallet 6 hours ago. It is still at 0 confirmations.

Further Detail:

- the network  propagation is very low at 0-1%
- I used the recommended fees setting(the middle setting)
- I sent a couple cents from the same wallet to the same receiving wallet and it went through to 3 confirms after about an hour or so.
- my wallet is :
- and the hash is:

So, now I'm stuck and can't find any info online that I understand to help me with this.  Any help will be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a miners fee after you send your bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22693/is-it-possible-to-add-a-miners-fee-after-you-send-your-bitcoins)

Comment: Rewards aren't necessary here! Its a free and open Q&A site. I think the only rewards allowed here are the built-in bounties.

Comment: Looking at the blockchain.info [treechart](https://blockchain.info/de/tree/114397417), didn't the final (already confirmed) transaction spent the output created in the unconfirmed transaction? How would it be possible that the final transaction could go through before the used input was validated then?

Comment: sorry, I didn't really understand what your saying, I'm too novice : (

Answer (score 5):

When you look at [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/en/tx/5bf37f4f40b4f47c9f5f66e4de2f788ccb366c038c8a1184f68f1984d4bc8e9f) you will see that your transaction contains 0.0001 BTC which is not zero fee, so it is very likely that your transaction will be confirmed.

You have various options if the transaction doesn't get confirmation:

Reset your blockchain and wait until it's up to date again (keep your device on power and connected to internet). After the rescan, stuck transactions should be gone and your BTC free to spend again.

OR

Relay stuck transactions to a miner that accepts non-standard fees. You can use the `trusted peer` option for this, just remember to clear that option after your problem is resolved. Also see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Free_transaction_relay_policy.

From: [UnstickLowFeeTransactions](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/wiki/UnstickLowFeeTransactions)

Note: There is certain time after blockchain.info clears the transaction if it isn't taken by any miner +- 72 hours. I would recommend you wait this time.

OR

1. Download electrum or any bitcoin client
2. Dump your private keys from blockchain.inf and import them. Use [Pywallet](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34028.0) to delete that transaction from your wallet.
3. Create whole new bitcoin wallet at blockchain.info and sent entire transacion again. (Wallet mustn't be created under same account).
4. send your transaction again.

Conditions for confirmation of zero transactions:

1. Transaction is smaller than 10 thousand bytes.
2. All outputs are 0.01 BTC or larger.
3. Its priority is large enough (see the Technical Info section below)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees

Source of my post:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=274185.0

https://bitcoinarmory.com/download/troubleshooting/

Comment: Condition 2 is not met, one of the outputs was 4.2mBTC.

Comment: @murch Does this mean that I did something wrong? Its been over 48 hours now and still no coins. I'll just wait I guess, thanks a lot everybody for your responses, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

just sit and wait ;)

https://blockchain.info/en/tx/5bf37f4f40b4f47c9f5f66e4de2f788ccb366c038c8a1184f68f1984d4bc8e9f

Estimated Confirmation Time  Very Soon (High Priority)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your supporting comment.  It's been over 48 hours now, may I please bounty or pay you to help undo my transfer, It would be very appreciated, thanks for any consideration.

Comment: Not a good answer or explanation.